# Find days where no entry exists in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable with a list of dates per employee, an example for one employee:

```
employee  date
emp1      Monday 3rd 10am
emp1      Monday 3rd 12am
emp1      Monday 3rd 3pm
emp1      Tuesday 4th 9am
emp1      Wednesday 5th 2pm
emp1      Friday 6th 10am
emp1      Saturday 7th 10am
```

In my example Thursday is missing.
I want to find out if any day from Monday to Friday has no record.

Each employee can have more than one record per day, and weekends can have records too.  So counting the records doesn't help.  I can see a very slow way to do this would be loop through 5 times and check until I find each weekday; and repeat for each employee.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you looking to do this via SQL or via recursive processing in VB?

Comment: thanks for the edit ya23

Comment: @Mort happy to use either, using MSSQL or VB.NET.  Whichever is less laggy.

Comment: Are they stored as dates on the database, or strings?

Comment: They are stored as dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sql should give you a datatable of employees, per week, who have not had 5 weekdays recorded on the database:

```
   select emp_id, week_no, count(*)
      from
      (select distinct emp_id,datepart(ww, work_Date) week_no, datepart
       (dw,work_Date) weekday 
      from dates_table
              where datepart(dw,pet_work_Date) in (2,3,4,5,6 )) as v
            group by emp_id, week_no
            having count(*) < 5;
```

This sql will give a more informative datatable identifying which day was missing:

```
select emp_id, week_no, 
  sum(mon_present) mon_present,  
  sum(tue_present) tue_present,  
  sum(wed_present) wed_present,  
  sum(thu_present) thu_present,
  sum(fri_present) fri_present,
  count(*)
from
(select distinct emp_id,datepart(ww, work_Date) week_no, datepart(dw,work_Date) weekday ,
  case when datepart(dw,work_Date) = 2 then 1 else 0 end mon_present,
  case when datepart(dw,work_Date) = 3 then 1 else 0 end tue_present,
  case when datepart(dw,work_Date) = 4 then 1 else 0 end wed_present,
  case when datepart(dw,work_Date) = 5 then 1 else 0 end thu_present,
  case when datepart(dw,work_Date) = 6 then 1 else 0 end fri_present
  from dates_table_test
where datepart(dw,work_Date) in (2,3,4,5,6 )) as v
group by emp_id, week_no
having count(*) < 5
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround could be:

Fetch all the data from the database.

Then for each employee, use string matching(use regex) to select all the days and count the number of entries for particular day. If any of the seven days count is 0 then you could conclude that particular day has no record for that particular employee.